# How to remove the top two empty rows in the excel sheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Below the sample codes. It's may help you..
When i'm change the row number(1) into 5 then seven rows are empty in excel sheet.**(LOCATION : setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);)**

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");  
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);       

    $fields = array('ram','one','two');     
    $col = 0;   
    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
        $col++;
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Export.csv"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: And what this has to do with `mysql`

Comment: To display the data from mysql into excel sheet .xlsx But the top two rows are dynamically empty...I was try to static data like ('ram','one','two') but these field also make top two empty rows. I don't know why..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");  
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);       

$field = array('ram','one','two');      
$col = 0;   
foreach ($fields as $field)
{
  if(empty($field)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1,     $field);
    $col++;
  }
}

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Export.csv"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Surely you mean `if(!empty($field)){`

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `$field` but foreach references `$fields`.... that `s` makes a lot of difference

```
$field = array('ram','one','two');
```

and

```
foreach ($fields as $field)
```

Try defining your array with the correct variable name

```
$fields = array('ram','one','two');
```